# Add year to short notes with biblatex-chicago?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biblatex-chicago

I'm currently typesetting a book project, using biblatex-chicago for footnotes and references, but am struggling to customise the format of short notes. The default setting gives these with only the author and the title, for example:

Albert Einstein, *Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement*.

However, ideally I would want to also include the year, i.e. to have either of the following:

Albert Einstein, *Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement* (1956).

Albert Einstein, *Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement*, 1956.

Does anyone know if this is possible? I am happy to switch bibliography package if that's necessary, but have tried a few options and nothing seems to work.

Here is a MWE of what I currently have:

**bibfile**

```
@book{einstein1956,
author = {{Albert Einstein}},
title = {Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement},
year = {1956},
}
```

**texfile**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[notes, short]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\begin{document}
    Some text to be referenced.\autocite{einstein1956}
\end{document}
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the date to the `cite:short` macro using the `xpatch` package.

And rather than using `author={{Albert Einstein}}` which will sort under `A` in the bibliography, specify the author as `author={Einstein, Albert}` and change the format of `labelname` using `\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}` to print the full name in your short citation.

(Also, use `\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}` instead of the deprecated `\bibliography{bibfile}`)

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{einstein1956,
  author = {Einstein, Albert},
  title  = {Investigations on the Theory of the Brownian Movement},
  date   = {1956}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[notes, short]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{given-family}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptobibmacro{cite:short}
  {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
   \usebibmacro{date}}
  {}
  {}
\begin{document}
\null\vfill
Some text to be referenced.\autocite{einstein1956}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]